# Как подменить HTTP-заголовки ответа на прокси-сервере?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, proxy

Локально запускается прокси-сервер. От клиента к нему поступает `http.request`, который он передает на сервер в сети. От сервера в сети прокси-сервер получает ответ, подменяет HTTP-заголовки и передает далее клиенту.

Прокси пишу на *Node.js*. Не могу получить заголовок клиентом. *Node.js* не обязателен - можно любым способом.

*Код отредактирован*

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(9000);
function onRequest(req, res) {
    var options = {
        hostname: 'www.google.ru',
        port: 80,
        path: req.url
    };
    var proxy = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.on('end', function() {
            res.headers['Random-Header'] = 'Random-Content';
        });
        res.pipe(res, {
            end: true
        });
    });
    req.pipe(proxy, {
        end: true
    });
}
```

**Обновление**

Попробовал перенести строчку `http.createServer(onRequest).listen(9000);` так чтобы она была после определения `onRequest`, но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Может проблема в том, что `onRequest` определен после первого использования?

Comment: Во-первых, что насчет того, что у вас получается две переменных `res`? Вы пытаетесь установить значение не у той переменной. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/dp3rmy41/). Во-вторых, в документации указано `response.setHeader(name, value)` - возможно, вариант через `.headers[...]` не является верным. В-третьих, в _Node.js_ я не разбираюсь, вижу `.pipe()`, но всё же сомнения остаются: а ответ клиенту происходит после того, как пришел ответ от удалённого сервера?

Comment: `function funcName(){}` поднимается интерпретатором вверх, функцию, объявленную таким образом можно безболезненно использовать в коде выше ее объявления.

Comment: @Aktash с `response.setHeader` вы погорячились: у вас же переменная `res` называется. Кстати, заголовок ведь должен быть установлен перед отправкой данных. А у вас вроде он устанавливается в самом конце (`_res.on('end'`).

Comment: @Regent Две `res` поправил. `.headers[...]` заменил на `response.setHeader`. С _Node.js_ я пишу впервые, поэтому плохо ищу в документации и не могу найти как работает `.pipe()` в деталях. Не нашёл пока способа проверить отправляется ли ответ клиенту только после того как пришел ответ от удалённого сервера. Если с прокси-сервер запускается с таким кодом, то по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:9000/` в браузере открывается гугл, так что подозреваю, что маршрутизация всё-таки работает правильно.

Comment: @Regent Вы правы с `response` я поторопился. Поправил. По поводу своевременности установки заголовка. Я тоже думаю, что заголовок изменяется уже после того как ответ отправляется клиенту. Я не могу найти в документации событие, которое возникает после получения ответа от удаленного сервера, но перед срабатыванием `pipe`.

Comment: @Aktash у вас сейчас, кстати, `_res.setHeader`, а должно быть, насколько я понимаю, `res.setHeader`. Если работает в браузере - это уже хорошо. По поводу события: думаю, `function(_res) { ... }` вызывается как раз тогда, когда получен ответ от удалённого сервера. Поэтому имеет смысл попробовать просто `res.setHeader(...)`, без оборачивания в `_res.on('end'`.

Comment: @Regent Поправил `_res.setHeader` на `res.setHeader`. Осознал что заголовок нужно править не полученный от удаленного сервера в прокси, а отправляемый клиенту. Извлек `res.setHeader(...)` из слушателя `_res.on('end'`. Теперь всё работает. Клиент получает измененный заголовок! Большое спасибо! Я могу пометить комментарий как правильный ответ?

Comment: На здоровье. Нет, не можете, но я могу разместить итоговый вариант как ответ - тогда вы сможете отметить его как правильный.

Comment: @Aktash, "поднимается интерпретатором вверх, функцию, объявленную таким образом можно безболезненно использовать в коде выше ее объявления."  Ох щи, JS не устает удивлять. Это только в глобальном scope работает? Где прочитать про эту штуку?

Comment: @dzhioev Это работает если функция объявлена на том же уровне что и вызов или выше, то есть работает не только в глобальном поле видимости. Так умеет далеко не только JavaScript (могу ошибаться  C#, Java, PHP и др.).

Comment: @dzhioev В других языках, интерпретатор сканирует код перед выполнением, составляет синтаксическое дерево. По этому дереву и происходит поиск при обращении к объекту (функции в этом языке тоже объекты). Не уверен что это действительно так в случае с JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоговом варианте кода (по сравнению с первоначальным) изменились три вещи:

- Одинаковые переменные `res` в функциях получили разные имена (`res` и `_res`). Заголовок должен устанавливаться для ответа, отсылаемого клиенту (`res`).
- `res.headers[...]` было заменено на `.res.setHeader(...)`. Не факт, что это было обязательно, но в документации указан метод `setHeader`.
- Строка `res.setHeader` была извлечена из обработчика события `end`, дабы заголовок устанавливался в начале ответа.

Сам код:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(9000);
function onRequest(req, res) {
    var options = {
        hostname: 'www.google.ru',
        port: 80,
        path: req.url
    };
    var proxy = http.request(options, function(_res) {
        res.setHeader('Random-Header', 'Random-Content');
        _res.pipe(res, {
            end: true
        });
    });
    req.pipe(proxy, {
        end: true
    });
}
```